# Order of columns returned in SQL query (With table join)

Tags: oracle

I am wondering what determines the order of columns returned in a SQL query.

For example, `SELECT * FROM SOMETABLE;`

```
SQ_ID   |BUS_TYPE   |VOIP     |LOCAL_PHONE
--------|-----------|---------|-------------
SQ000001|Business   |Y        |N
```

I am guessing the attribute `COLUMN_ID` determines this. In the case of a table join, for example, `SELECT * FROM SOMETABLE LEFT JOIN OTHERTABLE USING (SOME_COL);` how is the order now determine.

Comment: If you want a specific column order - just simply **specify** it! `SELECT VOIP, SQ_ID, LOCAL_PHONE, BUS_TYPE FROM .....`

Comment: @marc_s thanks, surely that is the way to go. I'm being questioned on how Oracle determines the natural order of columns in a join.

Comment: Rule of thumb: If no order is specified regard any order as random.

Answer (score 2):

The order of columns in `SELECT * FROM some_table` is determined by the `column_id` of each column, as seen in USER_TAB_COLUMNS.

The order of columns in `SELECT * FROM some_table JOIN other_table` is all the columns for each table starting with the leftmost table after the FROM clause.  In other words, this ...

```
SELECT * FROM some_table JOIN other_table
```

... is equivalent to this ...

```
SELECT some_table.*, other_table.* FROM some_table JOIN other_table
```

Changing that inner join to LEFT JOIN or RIGHT JOIN won't change the projection.

---

This is, of course, theoretical.  We should never use `select *` in production code.  Explicit column declarations, with table aliases when joining, are always safer.  Apart from better expression of intent, explicit projections protect our code from future changes to the tables such as adding a LOB column or a column name which creates ambiguity with a joined table's column.

Answer (score 1):

You can list the order of the colums in the Select statement:

```
SELECT SOME_COL, SOME_OTHER_COL
FROM SOMETABLE LEFT JOIN OTHERTABLE USING (SOME_COL)
```

But you also speak of the ID influencing the order and of ordering in general. So I think you could also be looking for ORDER BY to order the rows:

```
SELECT *
FROM SOMETABLE LEFT JOIN OTHERTABLE USING (SOME_COL)
ORDER BY SOME_COL
```

What also comes quite handy in this case is the use of aliases. Especally when both tables have coloums with the same name:

```
SELECT s.some_col, o.some_col
FROM SOMETABLE s LEFT JOIN OTHERTABLE o ON(o.id = s.id)
ORDER BY o.SOME_COL
```

I use the ON JOIN syntax in this case, because i find this more intuive when using aliases but it should also work with USING.